# Safari is not respecting decimals in CSS filter: blur()

Tags: css, filter, safari

I need to use subtle blurs on my text, so I'm using 0.6px blur filters. Firefox and Chrome seem to handle fractions of a pixel (decimals) well:

[image]

However, Safari (14.0 and newer) doesn't respect fractions of a pixel. Everything gets rounded up to the nearest integer.

[image]

You can see a live demo of these screenshots below. If you visit with Chrome and Firefox, you'll see sub-pixel blurs, but Safari jumps all the way to 1px, it doesn't do any fraction in between:

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.blur1 {
  filter: blur(1px);
}
.blur2 {
  filter: blur(0.6px);
}
.blur3 {
  filter: blur(0.001px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur1">Hello 1px</div>
<div class="blur2">Hello 0.6px</div>
<div class="blur3">Hello 0.001px</div>
```

Is there any way to fix this, or to circumvent this bug? How can I get my text to blur a fraction of a pixel in Safari MacOS and iOS?

Comment: I know safari also doesn’t handle line-height well either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of scaling and font-size setting, Safari can be made to look as though it is blurring 'fractionally' - it seems happy scaling fractionally but not blurring fractionally.

This snippet sets font-size inversely proportional to the required blur, keeps the blur at 1px and then scales down by the fraction which is the required blur:

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
}

.blur:nth-child(1) {
  --b: 1;
}

.blur:nth-child(2) {
  --b: 0.6;
}

.blur:nth-child(3) {
  --b: 0.1;
}

.blur:nth-child(4) {
  --b: 0.01;
}

.blur:nth-child(5) {
  --b: 0.001;
}

.blur {
  font-size: calc(1em / var(--b));
  line-height: calc(1.4em * var(--b));
  filter: blur(1px);
  width: calc(100% / var(--b));
  transform: scale(var(--b));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="blur">Hello 1px</div>
  <div class="blur">Hello 0.6px</div>
  <div class="blur">Hello 0.1px</div>
  <div class="blur">Hello 0.01px</div>
  <div class="blur">Hello 0.001px</div>
</div>
```

Tested on Safari iPadIOS 14 this seems to work. However, on Windows 10 Edge/Chrome somewhere betwen 0.01 and 0.001 the font size does not work correctly so it is not a general solution but maybe someone who understands the limits of accuracy in various CSS implementations can get further.